# Consulta SQL agrupando y con fecha más reciente

Tags: sql, ms-access

Ya he buscado entre las preguntas y no encuentro lo que quiero hacer.

Tengo una tabla del tipo:

```
user    dat1 dat2 dat3  fecha
----    ---- ---- ----  -----
antonio xxx  xxx  xxx  01/02/16
juan    xxx  xxx  xxx  17/02/16
antonio xxx  xxx  xxx  05/02/16
```

Quiero ver el registro más reciente de cada usuario.

Estoy trabajando en SQL sobre Access.

Con los datos anteriores el resultado deberia ser:

```
juan    xxx  xxx  xxx  17/02/16
antonio xxx  xxx  xxx  05/02/16
```

Se os ocurre algo?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con la siguiente sentencia, debería funcionar:

```
    SELECT [user], dat1, dat2, dat3 Max(fecha) FROM nombre_table GROUP BY [user] ORDER BY Max(fecha) DESC
```

Comment: Eso funciono a la primera. Gracias Emiliano.

Comment: @EricDrave buenisimo que te haya solucionado. Marca la respuesta como solucionado para cerrarla. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

No tengo claro cómo lograstes que te funcione la respuesta aceptada. Normalmente, MS Access debería darte un error quejándose de que `dat1, dat2, dat3` no se pueden usar por sí solos en el `SELECT` porque no forman parte de la expresión `GROUP BY`.

Y aunque funcionara, como se puede en bases de datos como MySQL, en realidad no queda claro cual `dat1, dat2, dat3` te va a devolver.

En realidad, para escribir la consulta correctamente, se necesitaría una clave primaria. En tu caso, no es claro si tienes una.  Pero asumiendo que la combinación `user, fecha` es única, la forma correcta de escribir la consulta es de esta manera:

```
select t.*
  from tabla t
 inner join (select user, max(fecha) as max_fecha
               from tabla
              group by user) g
    on g.user = t.user
   and g.max_fecha = t.fecha
```

Comment: Tienes razón sstan, no se como lo mire la primera vez. Se ve que con las prisas me apañe con una consulta de una consulta. Tu solución si que me funciona bien con una sola consulta. Muchas gracias sstan.

Answer (score 0):

Con la función `max` puedes hacerlo:

```
 select user, dat1, dat2, dat3, max(fecha)
 from nombre_tabla
 group by user ;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan rápida, pero con esa solucion me muestra todos los registros.  Estoy trabajando en sql sobre access.

Comment: @eric: No veo la diferencia entre esta respuesta y la que aceptastes.