# ¿Cómo seleccionar el producto con la fecha más reciente UNICAMENTE en el caso de que se haya comprado más de una vez?

Tags: oracle, sql, group-by

Me está resultado difícil escribir una consulta que partiendo de la tabla que muestro aquí abajo seleccioné la fecha más reciente para los productos repetidos.

```
categoria    / Id_liente  / Producto  / Fecha
Limpieza    /  1          /  Lejia    / 20-02-2018
Limpieza    /  1          / Lejia     / 31-12-2019
Alimentacion/  1          / Vino      / 20-12-2019
```

Después de ejecutar la consulta quedaría:

```
categoria    / Id_liente  / Producto  / Fecha
Limpieza    /  1          / Lejia     / 31-12-2019
Alimentacion/  1          / Vino      / 20-12-2019
```

En ORACLE he utilizado `Max(Fecha)` y `GROUP BY` pero me devuelve (lógicamente) la última transacción efectuada para cada cliente.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT CATEGORIA,ID_CLIENTE, PRODUCTO, MAX(FECHA) FECHA
                            FROM VENTAS
                            GROUP BY CATEGORIA, ID_CLIENTE, PRODUCTO
)
```

(Con un código similar al que he visto en [Consulta SQL agrupando y con fecha más reciente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36386/consulta-sql-agrupando-y-con-fecha-m%c3%a1s-reciente))

Me está costando ver cómo puedo hacer que SQL solo aplique `MAX(Fecha)` para cada tipo de producto y cliente.

¿Alguien me podría orientar para la realizar la consulta en ORACLE? un saludo.

Comment: Haz una subquery con tu query, dale un alias y ordena por fecha, haz select de todo esto.

Comment: Como el ejemplo que puse arriba? me sigue dando la ultima transaccion para cada cliente :s

Comment: te falta el order by DESC

Comment: El problema que tengo es que esa consulta solo me devuelve la ultima transaccion, en este caso 31-12-2019, y necesitaria tambien 20-12-2019 ya que el producto es differente.

Comment: quitale el max a la fecha, esto te dara todos los productos sin filtro de fecha, y agrega un limit 1 despues del order by

Comment: No logro entender completamente lo que buscas, ¿puede ser que quieras el último producto comprado por cada cliente y en cada categoria? Por otro lado el título de la pregunta menciona "que se haya comprado más de una vez", esto si no queda claro en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Podrías aclararnos estas dudas? saludos.

Comment: Buenos dias Patricio,
Por ejemplo en la tabla de arriba vemos que Lejia aparece dos veces para el mismo ID del cliente. 
En los casos en los que el producto y la ID del cliente coincidan mas de una vez, tengo que seleccionar unicamente la ultima transaccion.

Comment: Por favor, las respuestas van en el campo respuesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siguiendo lo que dices en tu último comentario: que buscas la última transacción según `FECHA` de cada cliente, producto, te cuento que una forma de resolverlo sería:

```
SELECT *
    FROM VENTAS V
    INNER JOIN (SELECT CATEGORIA, 
            ID_CLIENTE, 
            PRODUCTO, 
            MAX(FECHA) FECHA
            FROM VENTAS
            GROUP BY CATEGORIA, ID_CLIENTE, PRODUCTO
    ) M
    ON V.ID_CLIENTE = M.ID_CLIENTE
    AND V.CATEGORIA = M.CATEGORIA
    AND V.FECHA = M.FECHA
```

Básicamente tu subconsulta  nos trae la última fecha de cada `CATEGORIA`, `ID_CLIENTE` y `PRODUCTO`, la categoría del producto es opcional si cada producto tiene una única categoría. Luego aprovechamos estos datos en un `INNER JOIN` para obtener la fila que de `VENTAS` que coincida  en cuanto a la última fecha.

**Nota**: Esto tiene éxito en recuperar una fila por cada grupo, siempre que no existan más de una fila por fecha por cada grupo.

Otra forma un poco menos estándar  es usar [`row_number()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) para numerar por grupo y según el orden por fecha descendente, para luego quedarnos con el primer caso de cada grupo.

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (OVER PARTITION BY  CATEGORIA, ID_CLIENTE, PRODUCTO ORDER BY FECHA DESC) AS RN
        FROM VENTAS
)
SELECT  *
    FROM CTE
    WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Patricio! Funciona perfecto.